# Poedit Versions Cleanup

Tags: macos

I was checking my files and on /Users/***/Library/Application\ Support/Poedit/.Sparkle there are 2gb of different versions of Poedit.

How can I clean them? Poedit does it by default?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

> How can I clean them?

Err, *delete them?* Since you already located the files, that was the hard part, trashing them is the easy part…

Not sure what went wrong with Sparkle there...